# Show PHP page as an image content-type like Giphy.com images?

Tags: php, image, image-processing, giphy

It is very simple to show a PHP page like an image via - header('Content-Type: image/gif') but here is main thing that I want to implement:-

- How can I add meta tags and a link on that page like - https://media.giphy.com/media/l2SqcWByj8h7w0TEk/giphy.gif

It is an image content type but also contains a link and meta tags.

[Check Here > Image Content Type With Links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lA4nk.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the image and view source (CTRL + U) you will see it is infact HTML. They have used .htaccess or routing to point what appears to be an image URL (https://media.giphy.com/media/l2SqcWByj8h7w0TEk/giphy.gif) to an HTML file where they have added the link and 'meta tags'.

You could try something like this to achieve a similar result:

**DISCLAIMER:** This code is not safe and could be injected so you would want to sanitise the parameters, check that file request is actually an image file etc.

**.htaccess**

Direct all requests to yourdomain.com/media/an-image.gif to media.php.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^media/(.*)\.(gif|jpg|png)$ media.php?image=$1&ext=$2
```

**media.php**

Write a php script to handle request, check if image exists etc and output HTML.

```
      if(is_file('/path/to/media/' . $_GET['image'] . '.' . $_GET['ext'])) {
?>   
         <html>
            <head>
                <title>IMAGE TITLE HERE</title>
                <!-- other head tags -->
            </head>
            <body>
                <div id="image_container">

                    <!-- You could load this from a database or from filename -->
                    <div class="title">IMAGE TITLE</div>

                    <!-- Quick way to load real image is to store the actual .gif in another file, say '/assets/' so you can load it without it being caught by .htaccess.
                    <img src="/assets/<?php echo $_GET['image'] . '.' . $_GET['ext'];?>"/>

                    <!-- Alternative way to to load image and output base64 encoded version (you would have to make a handler for each format -->
                    <img src="data:image/'<?php echo $_GET['ext'];?>';base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIA..." "/>
                    <div class="link">
                        <a href="#linkhere">THIS IS THE IMAGE LINK</a>
                    </div> 
                </div>   
            </body>                  
         </html>            

<?php
         exit();

      }

   }


   // Redirect or return a 404 here.
   header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
   echo 'Not Found!';
   exit();
```